# Django - child template extended CSS from parent template but fail to use its CSS

Tags: django

The `home.html` was successfully extended from `base.html`. However I found that the child template is not making use of its own CSS. I guess it's because the `base.html` doesn't have a `{% block %}` tag to allow the children templates to override the CSS. I have no idea where to add the `{% block %}` tag in `base.html`. If I just add `{% block head %}` in `base.html`, the `home.html` will not use the CSS from `base.html`.

**book/templates/base.html:**

```
<head>
    {% load static %}
    <title>BookStore</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link id="cssFile" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'book/master.css' %}">
</head>
```

**book/templates/book/home.html:**

```
<head>
    {% block head%}
    <style>
        #homePageBooks {
            /*width: 160%;*/
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            left: 210px;
            /*margin-left: 100px;;*/
            /*margin-right: 100px;*/
            margin-top: 60px;
        }

        .row1, .row2, .row3 {
            font-size: 12px;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 120px;
            margin-left: 60px;
            margin-right: 60px;
            margin-bottom: 100px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .bookImg {
            margin-bottom: 6px;
        }
    </style>
    {% endblock %}
</head>
```

Comment: Add `{% block head %}{% endblock %}` after all lines in head of `book/templates/base.html`

Comment: @floydya thank you! It worked, I didn't realise that the {% block %} tag can be used that way.